# How to pass a value to a date variable part of a subquery using where clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, declare, stored-functions

I would like to somehow have control of a declared variable through the where clause.

I have an example query like this:

```
DECLARE @dateplaceholder AS DATETIME
SET @dateplaceholder = '2019-06-01'
SELECT @dateplaceholder PLACEHOLDER_DATE, GETDATE() AS TODAY, SOME_DATE_AGO = (SELECT dateadd(DAY, -7, @dateplaceholder ))

GO
```

This would work as intended. Giving the following result:

[image]

Now, I want to control `@dateplaceholder`variable on where clause, so as to make my query, a view, that I can call:

`select * myqueryView where @dateplaceholder = '2018-01-01'`

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @dateplaceholder AS DATETIME
SET @dateplaceholder = '2019-06-01'
SELECT @dateplaceholder PLACEHOLDER_DATE, GETDATE() AS TODAY, SOME_DATE_AGO = (SELECT dateadd(DAY, -7, @dateplaceholder ))
WHERE SELECT @dateplaceholder = '2018-01-01'
GO
```

However, it will return no results as it is basically checking with the declared variable has that value in where clause, it won't `set`it.

Any way this can be worked out?

Comment: A `VIEW` cannot be parametrised. If you need to reference a variable you need to do outside of the `VIEW` or use a different type of object that can be parametrised; such as a Stored procedure or a inline table-value function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table-value function to return the data you need and then use the parameter value you want. Like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [YourQueryName]
(@dateplaceholder datetime)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT 
    @dateplaceholder PLACEHOLDER_DATE, 
    GETDATE() AS TODAY, 
    SOME_DATE_AGO = (SELECT dateadd(DAY, -7, @dateplaceholder ))
GO

DECLARE @dateplaceholder AS DATETIME
SET @dateplaceholder = '2018-01-01'

select * from [YourQueryName](@dateplaceholder)
```

If you prefer you can also use a StoredProcedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usersp_YourQueryName] @dateplaceholder AS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @dateplaceholder PLACEHOLDER_DATE, GETDATE() AS TODAY, SOME_DATE_AGO = (SELECT dateadd(DAY, -7, @dateplaceholder ))
END
GO

EXEC [usersp_YourQueryName] '2019-06-01'
```